# how do i define a variable for subsetting multiple columns of a data.table in i?

Tags: r, data.table

A common task of mine is filtering (subsetting) datasets in the data.tables format.  I want to subset rows in i in a complex sort of way with multiple column-specific boolean conditions. When I get a new dataset, it will have the same type of columns and I will want to filter them in the same way for all datasets.

To illustrate my task, let me first create an example data.table.

```
library(data.table)

dt <- data.table(a = seq(1,6), b = letters[seq(1,6)], c = rep(c(4,3,2)))
```

This yields

```
   a b c
1: 1 a 4
2: 2 b 3
3: 3 c 2
4: 4 d 4
5: 5 e 3
6: 6 f 2
```

.  Suppose I want to apply the following filtering criteria to the columns:

```
 dt[b != 'd'][c < 4][a < 6]
```

yielding

```
 a b c
1: 2 b 3
2: 3 c 2
3: 5 e 3
```

.  Is there a way to convert that filtering criteria into a variable so that I can just tag it onto the end of the data.table?

I tried

```
x <- [b != 'd'][c < 4][a < 6]
dt[x]
```

but this throws the error

```
Error: unexpected '[' in "x <- ["
```

.  This would be great because I could update the filtering strategy by changing just the variable `x` and have this filter then apply to all data.tables.

Comment: You need `i1 <- dt[, b != 'd' & c < 4 & a < 6]; dt[i1]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is to applied on different dataset, `quote` the expression and evaluate it on each dataset

```
i1 <- quote(b != 'd' & c < 4 & a < 6)
dt[dt[, eval(i1)]]
#   a b c
#1: 2 b 3
#2: 3 c 2
#3: 5 e 3
```

Comment: and also: `dt[eval(i1)]`